# Keyframe not working

Tags: animation, keyframes

I'm new to Blender and I don't know what is happening. When I want to do an animation, first I select all the parts of the rig at frame 1 and insert keyframes. Then, I go to frame x and move the parts I want.

My problem is that I'm trying to do the same with the eyes and when I close them, they are closed at every frame, even at the first one. What I am trying to say is that it's not doing the animation, the eyes are closed by default when I do that.

I'm a beginner, so I have not created this model, but the eyes are controlled by these (if that's of any help).

[image]

Comment: Please upload your file

Comment: I don't know if there is a way to upload it, so here it is: https://mega.nz/#!u1JEzAoa!f82G_TN0V7ZX_7AaKuS7V0Cv4LtmodWU8cGpD-olBkc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your keying set is "LocRot", every time you press I or place automatic keyframes, some Loc and Rot keyframes are created, but not scale values.

Your blinking eyes are drived by a scale value, so simply set your keying set as "LocRotScale" and you'll be OK.

[image]

Comment: Oh yes, thank you very much, I thought I have tried that before but it seems not.